# Git how to rename a folder/package remotely?

Tags: git, github, package, rename

I accidentally named my package the wrong thing and I pushed it to github before I noticed. I renamed it locally, but when I push it again it hasn't tracked the changes made since it was just a couple of capitalization errors. How do I fix the remote capitalization errors? I mean its not a huge deal, but I would prefer to maintain consistency.

Comment: It is not clear what was not named correctly. What "package" are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[the manpage of git remote says](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html)

```
git remote rename <old> <new>
```

Comment: And what do I enter for old/new? I don't think I can use my local directories can i?

Comment: old is the old name on your remote repository new in the name you want it suits

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the OS you are on, the change in the casing of a path may not be picked up locally - in Linux it is. A way around it is to

```
mv somepath/filename temp
git add -A
git commit -m "changing the case of a dir"

mv temp SomePath/FileName
git add -A
git commit --amend -m "changed somepath/filename to SomePath/FileName"
```

You can also just try

```
git mv -f somepath/filename SomePath/FileName
git commit -m "changed somepath/filename to SomePath/FileName"
```

But you will need to not be in that directory for this to work and may need to `git reset --hard` from the root of the repository if on Windows or OSX to force the working directory to be updated.